# Configuration hosts of Ubuntu 14.04 for puppet

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, puppet

I try to install puppet and I'm following this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/puppet.html#puppet-preconfiguration).
So I've changed my /etc/hosts on both sides (server/client). And I'm able to ping.

So for example on the masterside:

```
192.168.xx.xx puppetclient.example.com puppetclient
```

Try ping to client

```
ping puppetclient.example.com
64 bytes from puppetclient.example.com (192.168.140.155): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.304 ms
```

So that seems to work. But further on in my configuration I want to show the certs which want to connect with my master:

```
$ sudo puppet cert list
  "puppetagent-virtual-machine.localdomain" (SHA256) 3A:B3:8A:56:81:0C:D2:18:79:63:AE:FD:4A:ED:5B:3F:77:36:AA:51:17:A7:99:1D:5E:68:C1:78:FD:99:58:46
```

I thought it would be `puppetclient.example.com` and not `puppetagent-virtual-machine.localdomain`

Someone who can help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `sudo puppet cert list` uses the information provided in the certificate( of agent, which is sent to master) instead of the DNS name.

So, I think, it is something with the certificate which is generated on the puppet agent side. The puppet agent while generating the certificate uses the hostname instead of its DNS name.

I am not sure, whether we can manually generate the certificates on the puppet agent or pass some custom information(like name which want) to the puppet agent when it is generating the certificate.

**UPDATE:**

I have found this: https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/configuration.html#certname

which says, the `certname` can be changed with the `node_name_value` and `node_name_fact` settings, although you should only do so if you have a compelling reason.

Comment: yes my agent is using its hostname to create/name the certificate instead of its DNS name. But I don't know why and how to change it.

Comment: Check [this](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/configuration.html#certname) or for a quick hack you can just change hostname to dnsname when you run puppet agent.

P.S: Updated the answer with the same details.